# Generate Text PDF with Bytes error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to generate PDF, but I have some problems with the bytes error that hanging the system and web.

I found some reason why but could not find a solution yet.

When I debug, my codec stopped here and freeze my web. Then after I restart it will be very slowly loading my page.

I found out that if I wrote more than 200 characters, it will bug the system. But if I don't, everything will be fine. I just want to know why.

I am not very expert here. Thanks for you help. This is the codec debug where it stopped and frozen. Can anyone help me?

```
Dim bytes() As Byte
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(strNewPathPDF, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
        bytes = reader.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
        fs.Close()
```

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with C#?

Comment: c# can participate too ..

Comment: Are you running Avast or AVG? [Don't](http://dottech.org/102416/why-i-switched-from-avast-to-avira-better-computer-performance-and-speed-opinion/).

Comment: i using FortiClient anti virus.. , what wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know FortiClient, but Avast and AVG hook into the Win32 file API and attempt to preprocess many file types, including PDFs. They are notorious for blocking file access when opening large files. Try disabling your antivirus. If that doesn't work you have to post code that duplicates the problem for us to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You get the nreco dll from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PdfGenerator/

And you can use the following code:

```
                 NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter nPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();

nPdf.Size = PageSize.Letter;

PageMargins mar = new PageMargins();
mar.Bottom = -5;
mar.Left = -5;
mar.Top = -5;
mar.Right = -5;
nPdf.Margins = mar;

nPdf.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
var pdffilename = "D:\Documents"+"filename" + ".pdf";

var htmltext="this testing pdf"
var pdfBytes = nPdf.GeneratePdf(htmltext);
File.WriteAllBytes(pdffilename, pdfBytes);
```